# MYSQL SUM() with IF

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have three following tables. Simplified here for better understanding.

[image: simplified tables]
There are orders and there are writers. Each writer is assigned a specific *writer_alias*. A writer gets paid for each order that he completes and that order gets approved as well(when order_status is 1). But only when the sum of total amount of approved orders is greater than $200.

I need to calculate ACID_COST or IMMEDIATE_PAYABLE which will be equal to sum of costs for any writer whose sum is greater than $200 and payment_status of that particular order is 0. I am not sure if I am able to explain it here. This is as far as I have reached with this, but it only calculates sum of all approved orders' amount.

```
"SELECT SUM(tblpayment.amount) AS PAYABLES FROM tblpayment, tblorder WHERE tblorder.order_alias=tblpayment.order_alias AND tblorder.order_status=1 AND tblpayment.payment_status=0"
```

The desired answer here might be 0 in this case because writer_alias(16) approved amount is 30 which is less than 200 and writer_alias(15) approved amount is 10 which is again less than 200.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The corrected tables picture is here.

[image]

Comment: GROUP BY... HAVING...?

Comment: Can you show the desired answer here..

Comment: The desired answer here might be 0 in this case because writer_alias(16) approved amount is 30 which is less than 200 and writer_alias(15) approved amount is 10 which is again less than 200.

Comment: I think I made the wrong diagram. My bad. Let me make a new one in 5 minutes.

Comment: All you want is to show the total amounts when a writer ha earned 200 in total right?  Did you run the suggested query below?

Comment: Jelle, yes you are right. I want to show the total amounts when a writer has earned 200 in total. Which suggested query? the one I mentioned? yes it returned with sum of amounts of orders that are approved.

Comment: btw, I have uploaded the correct table diagram with desired result.

Comment: Asim: I meant the query in the answer I gave you...

Comment: any update on this guys? Strawberry, anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the result of an aggregate function in the `WHERE` clause. Instead, you should use `HAVING`, like this:

```
SELECT tblorder.writer_alias, SUM(tblpayment.amount) AS PAYABLES
FROM tblpayment, tblorder
WHERE tblorder.order_alias = tblpayment.order_alias
  AND tblorder.order_status = 1
  AND tblpayment.payment_status = 0
GROUP BY tblorder.writer_alias
HAVING SUM(tblpayment.amout) > 200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(tblpayment.amount) AS PAYABLES 
FROM   tblpayment, tblorder 
WHERE  tblorder.order_alias=tblpayment.order_alias 
AND    tblorder.order_status=1 
AND    tblpayment.payment_status=0
and    PAYABLES > 200
group by writer_alias
```

Something like this?

Comment: tried it in PHMYadmin. invalid use of group function... that is the error I received.

Comment: another error that I received is 'Unknown column 'PAYABLES' in 'where clause' ' but thats okay.